# Access VBA Checkbox error 2447

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ok, I'm getting the error 2447 when trying to create a new record in my database.  Here is the code that is have.

```
'This checks the record each time a record is changed to see if it needs to display the text boxes
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.SigCheck = 1 then <--This is where I'm getting the error.
SigSerialtxt.Visible = True
SigSeriallbl.Visible = True
SigAssettxt.Visible = True
SigAssetlbl.Visible = True
Else
SigSerialtxt.Visible = False
SigSeriallbl.Visible = False
SigAssettxt.Visible = False
SigAssetlbl.Visible = False
End if
End Sub
```

I've tried to change the variable to True, as well as -1, but neither of the work.  I'm lost as to what to use.

Comment: Me.SigCheck is a checkbox, I want the form to check each time a record is pulled up to see if value of the item is true.  If it is true then display the textboxes.

Comment: When I added the msgbox statement I get the error when hitting new record.  But only when hitting new record.  If I'm looking at a record that has a value already it is, it pops up as 0, for null.  I set the default value to the value that is in the table, so I don't know why it's coming back with an error when I try to create a new one.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I set the default to 0, now there is no error and it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue, I set the default to 0, now there is no error and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already figured it out, but I wanted to add another answer if someone, like me, stumbles across this post later.

You could also do some value/error checking. For example, you could have also done:

```
if IsNull(Me.SigCheck)=false AND Me.SigCheck=1 Then
...
end if
```

Alternatively, you can also use `true` for 1 and `false` for 0. A null checkbox I believe has the square in the middle of it.